# Why does the top MVC `_Layout` navbar overwrite the body?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm a very noob CSS coder, but I would expect that if I add another line or a taller element in the navbar, making it higher, to push the body down. Instead it covers the top of the body, and I must increase padding on the body to push its top down below the navbar.

What CSS is at play here and why?

Comment: Potentially an absolutely position element? Check the css in the browser tools to see if there are any `position: xxx;` properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ProfK** Hi there.
All you need to do here is add this css.

```
<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

And that will fix it for you.

---

**Added to this**

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ndz2ch3/)** this does what you are asking here.
What I do here is remove the `padding-top` or set it to zero.
I use a `div` to wrap the **navbar** and give this `div` a class of `this-wrap`and set the height to 50px the same as the height of the navbar.
Now what ever you place next in the body will be lower than the navbar and not under the navbar.

Does this help?... to act more as you expect.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I'm asking why. I expect the _Layout, especially, as it's done for me, to be more flexible, and the layout more fluid.

Comment: Hi. Using Bootstrap layout the navbar is in the body, so you have to allow for that. Maybe explain when you say more fluid... what are you looking here for? Little more info so others may help as well.

Comment: By more fluid I meant e.g. that the container div below the navbar header would adjust downward if the header increased in height.

Comment: Have a look at the **Fiddle** and what I have added to the post above.

Comment: If I change the FIddle example to have 7 "content" menu items (instead of 1), it wraps to the next line and covers the text. This is what mine is doing.